# How to return only the rows that meet a specific condition on Slot grouped by Num

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a sample data frame that I am working with

```
ID <- c("ID001","ID001","ID003","ID003","ID003","ID006","ID007","ID007","ID009","ID010",
        "ID021","ID021","ID023","ID023","ID023","ID026","ID027","ID207","ID023")
Type <- c("Length","Length","LengthTest","LengthTest","Length","LengthTest","LengthTest","Length","LengthTest","LengthTest",
          "LengthTest","Length","LengthTest","LengthTest","LengthTest","Length","LengthTest","LengthTest","LengthTest")
PassFail <- c("PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","FAIL","FAIL_AVG","FAIL#PTS","PASS","FAIL","PASS",
              "FAIL_SIG","PASS","PASS","FAIL#NODATA","PASS","PASS","FAIL","FAIL#PTS","PASS")
Slot <- c(1.0,1.0,1.1,1.2,2.0,2.1,2.2,1.0,1.1,1.2,
          1.3,2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3)
Num <- c(1111,1112,1112,1112,1113,1113,1113,1114,1114,1114,
         1114,1115,1115,1115,1115,1115,1115,1115,1115)

df <- data.frame(ID,Type,PassFail,Slot,Num)
```

df

```
      ID       Type    PassFail Slot  Num
   ID001     Length        PASS  1.0 1111
   ID001     Length        PASS  1.0 1112
   ID003 LengthTest        PASS  1.1 1112
   ID003 LengthTest        PASS  1.2 1112
   ID003     Length        FAIL  2.0 1113
   ID006 LengthTest    FAIL_AVG  2.1 1113
   ID007 LengthTest    FAIL#PTS  2.2 1113
   ID007     Length        PASS  1.0 1114
   ID009 LengthTest        FAIL  1.1 1114
   ID010 LengthTest        PASS  1.2 1114
   ID021 LengthTest    FAIL_SIG  1.3 1114
   ID021     Length        PASS  2.0 1115
   ID023 LengthTest        PASS  2.1 1115
   ID023 LengthTest FAIL#NODATA  2.2 1115
   ID023 LengthTest        PASS  2.3 1115
   ID026     Length        PASS  3.0 1115
   ID027 LengthTest        FAIL  3.1 1115
   ID207 LengthTest    FAIL#PTS  3.2 1115
   ID023 LengthTest        PASS  3.3 1115
```

I am trying to reduce this data frame to only contain rows based on a specific condition. I want to group by `Num` with the summary done on `Slot` column.

The `Slot` column generally has whole numbers (1,2,3,etc) but if the slot has additional rows with (0.1,0.2,etc), I want to just return only 1 row per slot (1,2,3,etc) grouping by `Num` and also looking at PassFail column for any fails. 
If all are **passes** in the `Passfail` column for that `Slot` and `Num`, return the first PASS. 
If there is any **fail** in the sublevels of slots, return the first FAIL corresponding to the `Slot` number grouped by `Num`.

Note: In df, anything that has FAIL in PASSFAIL column is considered a failure.

**Desired Output**

```
     ID       Type    PassFail Slot  Num
  ID001     Length        PASS  1.0 1111
  ID001     Length        PASS  1.0 1112
  ID003     Length        FAIL  2.0 1113
  ID009 LengthTest        FAIL  1.1 1114
  ID023 LengthTest FAIL#NODATA  2.2 1115
  ID027 LengthTest        FAIL  3.1 1115
```

I am trying to get any slots that have sublevels by doing this

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Num) %>% filter(n_distinct(Slot) > 1)
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to proceed with this problem. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution using `case_when`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Num) %>% 

  # create a temporary column PassFail1
  mutate(PassFail1 = case_when(
    all(PassFail == "PASS") ~ "PASS", 
    PassFail == "FAIL#NODATA" ~ "FAIL#NODATA",
    any(grepl("FAIL", PassFail)) ~ "FAIL")) %>% 

  # remove the rows that have PASS mixed with FAIL in the same Num group 
  filter(!(PassFail == "PASS" & PassFail1 == "FAIL")) %>% 

  # remove duplicates
  distinct(PassFail1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 

  # clean up
  select(-PassFail1) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   ID    Type       PassFail     Slot   Num
#>   <fct> <fct>      <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 ID001 Length     PASS         1.00 1111.
#> 2 ID001 Length     PASS         1.00 1112.
#> 3 ID003 Length     FAIL         2.00 1113.
#> 4 ID009 LengthTest FAIL         1.10 1114.
#> 5 ID023 LengthTest FAIL#NODATA  2.20 1115.
#> 6 ID027 LengthTest FAIL         3.10 1115.
```

Created on 2018-04-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This works but I am skeptical about hard coding PassFail == "FAIL#NODATA" ~ "FAIL#NODATA". Why'd we have to do that? I might different fail types and your code might only look for fail#nodata. can you check this?

Comment: Because otherwise it will lump everything together in the same category with `FAIL`

Answer (score 0):

This gets close to your desired output.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[order(Slot),{mytest=sum(PassFail=='PASS')==.N;.(ID=ID[1],Type=Type[1],PassFail=ifelse(mytest,rep('PASS',length(mytest)),rep('FAIL',length(mytest))),Slot=Slot[1])},by=.(Num,intslot=as.integer(Slot))][order(Num,Slot)]
```

It ignores the "notes" of PassFail and just treats anything that isn't "PASS" as a "FAIL"